# Reducing the sorting time of a large number of numbers

Tags: performance, beginner, ruby, sorting

I have to sort many large numbers in a given time limit. The program below works, but not when the test cases reaches \$10^6\$, in which case it exceeds the time limit.

```
def tsort(tests)
        sorted_array = []
        1.upto(tests) do
            input_num = gets.chomp.to_i
            sorted_array[input_num] = 1
        end
        #puts sorted_array.sort!
        sorted_array.each_index {|index| puts index if sorted_array[index] == 1}
    end

    test_cases = gets.chomp.to_i
    tsort(test_cases)
```

I wanted to ask if there was a better way to do this. Perhaps an algorithm will help me accomplish this.

Comment: Quick sort? Merge sort? Bogo sort? Did you even check Wiki's sort page?

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. This looks like a perfectly fine question to me.

Comment: Your question asks about reducing the sorting time, yet the only line that does any sorting is commented out. All you have is an input/output routine. Could you clarify the question?

Answer (score 8):

## Single Responsibility and Lying Names

The `tsort` method does too much. It both gets input from the user and stores that information in an array (a potentially large one at that, but more on that later). *Then* it prints the array. You should have three separate methods here and `tsort` should do one thing, *sort an array*. As it is, nothing actually gets sorted per se. You're just keeping the list sorted, which seems smart, but...

## Performance

Think about what happens when I give `gets.chomp.to_i` the number 100. The number 1 gets placed into the 100th position of the array. To get it back out, we have to then iterate over 100 positions. If I give it 1000 instead, we now have to make 1000 iterations in order to find it. That's 10 times as many iterations. This method gets exponentially slower. It is no surprise that inputting 10^6 exceeds the time constraints; it takes 10^6 iterations to print the number, *even if it's the **only** number in the array*.

This can be solved by implementing any number of well studied sorting algorithms. A quick google search should get you started. I recommend learning to bubble sort first, then move on to the more efficient algorithms. This assumes you're doing this for educational purposes. Otherwise, just use [Ruby's built in Array#sort method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-sort).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will implement this using bubble sort. @ckuhn203

Comment: @kunal: Remember, it depends on how many numbers (n) you are sorting. Bubble sort is proportional to n squared. If n is small, it's just fine. If n is large, it kills. Usually, you're best off with a quick, radix, heap, or merge sort. The built-in function probably does quick sort.

Comment: Absolutely true things @MikeDunlavey. I only suggested bubble sort because it's the easiest to learn and implement.